# Handle Must Be Valid Exception Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am working on an android app using Xamarin and receive the following exception.

```
Xamarin caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ArgumentException: Handle must be valid.
Parameter name: instance
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0000d] in <1bc3ec2e392f4f1a8cde1c9a163d2a4a>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in <0ce7e7a03dfb4c4b87eaf38b0e480d65>:0 
  at Android.Support.V4.Widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.set_Refreshing (System.Boolean value) [0x00060] in <27c17fe440cf491ba8255bcefade6e02>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewRenderer.<UpdateIsRefreshing>b__25_0 () [0x00000] in <a3e44144fef249b0888b761605dfca24>:0 
  at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in <0ce7e7a03dfb4c4b87eaf38b0e480d65>:0 
  at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <0ce7e7a03dfb4c4b87eaf38b0e480d65>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:ffc21647-8320-4065-b329-c8e7939eb92d (intptr,intptr)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I've tried adding a txt file, environment.txt, with the property to set the GC to old. However that did not work.
What other issues could cause this exception?

Comment: What is the code that is causing this exception?

Comment: had this issue today using sharedpreferences, few people experience this with recyclerview too. 
Bugzila report here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51478. Either downgrade to Xamarin.Android < 7.0 or use different implementation...

Comment: @Milen   Had this issue also with _SharedPreferences_, as soon as I tried to access it from multiple classes. _SharedPreferences_ is a **singleton**, so I made my `PreferencesManager` class a singleton, and it resolved this issue. (I am on Android 7.1)

Comment: @JScharmann have you managed to resolve it?